# probability confidence intervals for intercept

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model

I have a GAM model with about 10 variables and 450 observations. I ran a simple GAM regression using R and I noticed that everything looks OK, except that one of the splines has many zeros in the p value (0.000006427491961) and when I calculate the confidence intervals for the estimate, I get something like this for the intercept:
- estimate 0.06
- se 14
- 95%CI (40, 0.01)

Is this an issue of power? 
Also, I am not sure what happens if the intercept is significant, I have seen that is some cases in other analyses.

Comment: If you can publish the data (or simulated data), maybe someone can fit a GAM model using other software to see what happens. Otherwise, I cannot find the answers.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering in general what does that mean, not necessarily related to GAM. For some reason, I thought it was an issue of power.